# Can non-square matrices be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A is an $m \times n$ matrix where $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has a unique solution, is $A$ invertible?

I know the solution is true for $n \times n$ matrices, but what about in this case? Is there a counter example?

Comment: What is your definition of invertible? There are such things as left inverses and right inverses, but the usual definition of invertible (i.e. left-invertible and right-invertible at the same time) necessarily requires the matrix to be square.

Comment: It just means that $A$ has full column rank.

Answer (score 0):

invertible matrices are only defined for squared matrices

for you to calculate the inverse of a matrix you write down the steps in order to reach the identity
and you only have the identity for square matrices

what you wrote means that the vectors in your matrix are all linearly independent. If one of them were linearly dependent of the others, your matrix would not have a unique solution.